# How to add element to advanced array inside foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to add my data to my array inside my foreach loop.

I have almost done it successfully, except the array is too in-depth.

It's showing array->array->{WHAT I WANT}
When I need array->{WHAT I WANT}

Example, I'm needing it to be like:

```
Array
(
[home] => Array
    (
        [0] => Dashboard\Main@index
        [1] => GET
    )

[home/] => Array
    (
        [0] => Dashboard\Main@index
        [1] => GET
    )
)
```

When at the moment, it's showing:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [services/content-writing] => Array
            (
                [0] => Dashboard\Services@contentwriting
                [1] => GET
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [services/pbn-links] => Array
            (
                [0] => Dashboard\Services@pbnlinks
                [1] => GET
            )

    )
)
```

The code I'm currently using inside my foreach loop is:

```
$realArray = array();

// Services exist
if($services)
{
    // Sort them into our array
    foreach ($services as $service) {

        $servicePageName = $service->page_name;
        $serviceName = str_replace(' ', '', strtolower($service->name));

        $realArrayNew = array(
            "services/$servicePageName" => ["Dashboard\Services@$serviceName", 'GET']
        );

        array_push($realArray, $realArrayNew);

        //'home' => ['Dashboard\Main@index', 'GET'],

    }
}

return $realArray;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This portion of the code inserts a new subarray to your main array:

```php
$realArrayNew = array(
    "services/$servicePageName" => ["Dashboard\Services@$serviceName", 'GET']
);

array_push($realArray, $realArrayNew);
```

Replace it all with:

```php
$realArray["services/$servicePageName"] = ["Dashboard\Services@$serviceName", 'GET'];
```

That way your top level will have service names as keys.

Answer (score 1):

The `servicePageName` variable must be the key field on the `realArray` to get the results you want.

I'm presuming you input object array looks something like this:

```
[
    (int) 0 => object(stdClass) {
        name => 'contentwriting'
        page_name => 'content-writing'
    },
    (int) 1 => object(stdClass) {
        name => 'pbnlinks'
        page_name => 'pbn-links'
    }
]
```

If we do this:

```
$realArray = [];
if ($services) {
    foreach ($services as $service) {
        $servicePageName = $service->page_name;
        $serviceName = str_replace(' ', '', strtolower($service->name));
        $realArray["services/$servicePageName"] = [
            0 => "Dashboard\Services@$serviceName",
            1 => "GET"
        ];
    }
}
```

This is what we get on `realArray`:

```
[
    'services/content-writing' => [
        (int) 0 => 'Dashboard\Services@contentwriting',
        (int) 1 => 'GET'
    ],
    'services/pbn-links' => [
        (int) 0 => 'Dashboard\Services@pbnlinks',
        (int) 1 => 'GET'
    ]
]
```